# privacy concerns- database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

if i have this table:

```
users
-----
id_users (pk)
age
name
gender
salary
```

it is needed for each of these values an option to set visible or not in user profile.
What do you think that is the best way to do that?

For example hide the field salary to the person x, but allows to the person y.
basically some persons can watch some attributes.

thanks

Comment: When you say "user profile" do you mean their mysql account, or some higher level account (linux system account) that is used to access MySql indirectly?

Comment: user profile, like a perfil in a social network. You can hide some values of your profile. For example hide your salary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the default privacy will be show to all, then you can create a table to hold all the hide settings of a certain user to a certain user.

This is the table I would suggest, with a **compound PK of the three columns**:

```
hide_details
------------
visitor_id
user_id
what
```

Some sample data would be:

```
visitor_id      |       user_id     |       what
    1                       2               age
    1                       2               name
    3                       4               salary
```

This table schema will not have to be updated in the future if you add another column to your users' table. Suggestion, if you want to make this amazingly fast you can map the column names to integers, and use that in your application logic to compare against. E.g. name = 1, age = 2, etc... So, when you do the comparison to hide the name or not, you just check if there is a record with that integer in the hide array.

You can use it like the following: before you display a profile, you fetch all the hide records of that visitor to that profile, and put them in an array, and then display anything, which hasn't been hidden.

E.g.

```
$hide = array('name', 'age', 'salary');
```

Then, you can check like:

```
echo (in_array($hide)) ? '' : '<div>Name:'.$name.'</div>';
```

Comment: @Fel: It will be huge in the number of records, but it will be fully indexable. If you use my suggestion, to map the profile attributes to integers, then you won't have a slight problem with this. If you expect everyone to hide all the details, in which case the table would become huge, then do it reversed. Keep track of what the users want to show, and not what they want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a rights table for the persons who view the data. It can have the fields like id_person, may_view_age, may_view_salary, etc.

If visitors should be able to see some information of only certain people, then you need to also include a field for that in the users table, for example a department_id

It's hard to suggest something more specific if we don't know anything about your application.